# ASP.NET MVC + Populate dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

In my viewModel I have:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int SelectRegionId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Regions { get; set; }
}
```

But what do I have to do in my Controller/View to show the values? What I have now:
**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     var model = new ReUzze.Models.PersonViewModel
     {
         Person = new Person(),
         Regions = new SelectList(this.UnitOfWork.RegionRepository.Get(), "Id", "Name")
     };
     return View(model);
}
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Person.Address.Region)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectRegionId, new SelectList(Model.Regions, "Id", "Name"), "Choose... ")
 </div>
```

But it gives an error like this:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Can you add the error message you are receiving?

Comment: The Regions property in the model should be a normal list of items. Don't set it to a SelectList.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your ViewModel has a property of type 'IEnumerable', but SelectList does not satisfy that type.
Change your code like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int SelectRegionId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Regions { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Person.Address.Region)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectRegionId, Model.Regions, "Choose... ")
 </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You are creating SelectList instance twice. Get rid of one of them:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectRegionId, Model.Regions, "Choose... ")
```