# How to resolve: Cannot implicitly convert system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.ienumerable

Tags: c#, html, oop, razor, asp.net-webpages

I get this error

> Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

when trying to use a list to build out `@Html.DropDownList()` in a page built using C# Razor.

There is a C# class called `SubProgram.cs` with the following method that returns a `List<>`:

```
public List<SubProgram> SubProgramCodeDescriptionList()
{
    List<SubProgram> SubPrograms = new List<SubProgram>();

    // Get the list of SubPrograms for this AcctIII role_code from BudgetAcct3ToSubProgram  table 
    using (var db = Database.Open("DBNAME"))
    {
        string sql = @"
           SELECT l.SubProgramID, l.SubProgram + ' ' + l.SubProgramDesc AS SubProgramDesc
           FROM BARF_SubPrograms l
           WHERE l.Deleted = 0
           ORDER BY l.SubProgramDesc";

        var ListSubPrograms = db.Query(sql);

        foreach (var SubProgram in ListSubPrograms)
        {
            SubProgram item = new SubProgram ();
            item.SubProgramID = SubProgram.SubProgramID;
            item.SubProgramCodeDescr = SubProgram.SubProgramDesc;
            SubPrograms.Add(item);
        }

        db.Close();

        return SubPrograms;
    }
}
```

Here is the `SubProgram` class this method is a part of:

```
public class SubProgram 
{
    private int subprogramid;
    private string subprogramcode;
    private string subprogramcodedescr;

    public int SubProgramID 
    {
        get { return subprogramid; }
        set { subprogramid = value; }
    }

    public string SubProgramCode
    {
        get { return subprogramcode; }
        set { subprogramcode = value; }
    }

    public string SubProgramCodeDescr
    {
        get { return subprogramcodedescr; }
        set { subprogramcodedescr = value; }
    }
}
```

In the C# section of a Razor page, I create an object of type `SubProgram` to fill the `SubProgramList`:

```
// Create List boxes variable need for this add
List<SubProgram> SubProgramIDdropdownlist = new List<SubProgram>();

// Create SubProgram object so the method can be called
SubProgram subProgram = new SubProgram();

// Pass object to method SubProgramIDdropdownlist to return all of the SubPrograms
SubProgramIDdropdownlist = subProgram.SubProgramCodeDescriptionList();
```

In the body section of the HTML page below this C# Razor section above, I try to populate the DropDownList with the above code:

```
      <label class="FieldLabels">"Search SubPrograms"</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("SubProgramCodes",
             SubProgramIDdropdownlist,
               new  {
                      @id = "Column1",
                      @class = "EditTextBox",
                    }
              )
```

In this last section, the error occurs on SubProgramIDdropdownlist and this is where I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

There are other related posts, but not coming from a class method.  Please help, I know this needs to probably use a cast, but not even sure where to begin to get this to cast correctly.

Comment: How did you pass yor model on top of your Razor page?

Comment: I am not passing a model, I created a C# class with the code added above to create the class SubProgram.

Comment: Don't you have to pass an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the DropDownList?

Comment: Hope your answer is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482323/asp-net-razor-page-dropdown-list

Comment: You may reference the Microsoft docs to see that it takes in IEnumerable<SelectListItem>: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of:

1. On Razor Page using AsEnumerable

   `@Html.DropDownList("SubProgramCodes",SubProgramIDdropdownlist.AsEnumarable(),new { @id = "Column1", @class = "EditTextBox"})`

OR

2. Change the return type from `List<SubProgram>` to `IEnumerable<SubProgram>`

   `public IEnumerable<SubProgram> SubProgramCodeDescriptionList(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you tontonsevilla, your answer was helpful in solving this.

The final solution I came up with is that there was a conflict between two namespaces that both contained SelectListItem in both of them: System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.WebPages.Html.
Since I am primarily using Razor pages and not MVC for this project, I removed the @using System.Web.Mvc at the top of the Razor C# page because the error made it clear that SelectListItem is found in both System.Web.Mvc and in System.Web.WebPages.Html and I clearly needed to use one or the other, but not both.  I was able to cast these to get them to work, but this was just a lot of extra code that was not needed when I realized it was a name conflict.
Using both namespaces created a conflict between these two namespaces because SelectListItem appears to be in both namespaces.